# How to create a custom android button overlay?

Tags: java, android, xml

So to expand on the question stated, to my best understanding android apps have a set of `activities` such as the default `activity_main.xml` and you could even generate a login screen (`activity_login.xml`). After fiddling around with it I sort of feel comfortable with the way buttons work, yadda yadda, but my problem emerges when I want to create a game activity. I am not concerned about that part, I would just make another activity (`activity_gameplay.xml`) that I would run the game on. My problem is that I want to render my own custom buttons onto the screen which would be transparent and would be stationary while the actual game environment would be moving. Such as in Minecraft(android version obviously).

So to conclude I need to know how to render custom buttons, and though not included in the above, how to position the buttons accordingly sense the XML way only allows stuff such as upper left-hand corner etc.

Comment: Have you tried something? post the code

Comment: No I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. If you could give a key word to point me in the correct direction i would be grateful even for that.